# how can I get name (label value) of group (mat-optgroup) in select Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a html:

```
<mat-select #select [ngModel]="name" (selectionChange)="changing($event)">
    <span>
        <mat-optgroup [label]="'group 1'">
            <mat-option [value]="name1">{{name1}}</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="name2">{{name2}}</mat-option>
        </mat-optgroup>
    </span>
    <span>
        <mat-optgroup [label]="'group 2'">
            <mat-option [value]="name3">{{name3}}</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="name4">{{name4}}</mat-option>
        </mat-optgroup>
    </span>
</mat-select>
```

and here I want to get the group name i.e. `group 1`

```
changing(event) {
    console.log("group name is: ", event.label);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mat-select selectionChange get group angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156376/mat-select-selectionchange-get-group-angular)